# 3 Tables Share an Association table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two independent models that I want to link to a third shared model, through the same association. I could have two independent association tables, but would like to share to simplify the SQL reports.  *This example is hypothetical to simplify reality; don't beat it up.*

```rb
class Assoc < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :part
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :truck
end

class Part < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assocs
  has_many :cars, through: :assocs
  has_many :trucks, through: :assocs
end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assocs
  has_many :parts, through: :assocs
end

class Truck < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assocs
  has_many :parts, through: :assocs
end
```

This currently fails when saving a *Truck* or *Car*.  I'm not sure why exactly as `car.errors` doesn't reveal anything. It'd be a guess that the association may require 3 IDs to be present, whereas I just want it to have the *Part* and either *Car* *or* *Truck*, but not all three.  The above model translates to an SQL table that has the following schema:

### assocs

| column | type | example data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint | 1,2,3,... |
| part_id | bigint | 1,2,3,... |
| car_id | bigint | 1,2,3,... |
| truck_id | bigint | 1,2,3,... |

---

I think ideally, I'd prefer a table that had database class/subclass references.  Without giving it too much thought, something like the following, though it may need to its own question.

| column | type | example data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint | 1,2,3,... |
| vehicle_id | bigint | 1,2,3,... |
| vehicle_type | text | *Car* or *Truck*; the field could also be called *table_name* with *cars* or *trucks* being the value |

Comment: Amazing how what I'm after is exactly what polymorphic associations does (face palm), which I've never had to setup or use.  _That was easy._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my hypothesis above, I tested the association model and made the car/truck optional on the association, which worked:

```rb
class Assoc < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :part
  belongs_to :car,   optional: true
  belongs_to :truck, optional: true
end
```

I assume this now needs a validator to check for the presence of `car_id` or `truck_id`.  I haven't implemented it yet, but I assume *Assoc* should include something like this:

```rb
class Assoc < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :part
  belongs_to :car,   optional: true
  belongs_to :truck, optional: true

  validates :car_id,   presence: true, unless: :truck_id
  validates :truck_id, presence: true, unless: :car_id
end
```